# Escapar coma simple y doble en funcion onclick()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando pasar un texto en la funcion onclick() pero este texto contiene comillas simples y comillas dobles. de las cuales si las escapo me da error el PHP. No consigue escaparlas con \

este es mi fuente.

```html
$variable = "Texto de notas de prueba comida simple\' ahora comilla doble \" ";
echo '
<a href="javascrip:;" onClick="('.$variable.','1')" title="">hola</a>
';
```

Se podria hacer de alguna otra forma?, Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pulse el boton de hola me abra un modal, con los datos que le envio, desconozco si se podria hacer de alguna otra manera.

Comment: Creo que el error te da por que el atributo onclick, dentro de un elemento HTML se escribe así: `<a ... onclick="miFuncion()"></a>`

Comment: intenta esto y avisame si te sirve porque no comprendo muy bien tu pregunta <?php $variable ="esto 'esta en comilla simple' y esto en \"comilla doble\" "; echo $variable ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con la con `Heredoc` :

```
$nombre = "asd";

$str = <<<EOF
<p>Hello</p>
$nombre 
comillas ' ' ' ' ' 
comillas dobles " " " " 
EOF;

echo addslashes($str);
```

utilizas heredoc para crear el string deseado y luego solo la funcion addslashes!
referencia [heredoc php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Esto me valdria si no estuviera en la funcion onClick.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene cuando la variable contiene comillas dobles que no es posible escaparlas ya que el php da error. no se como solucionar esto.

La variable viene de un dato de base de datos. que viene asi: Texto de notas de prueba comilla simple ' ahora comilla doble "

```html
$variable = "Texto de notas de prueba comilla simple\' ahora comilla doble \" ";
echo '
<a href="javascrip:;" onClick="('.$variable.','1')" title="">hola</a>
';
```